# How do you use Apache Echarts to create Maps that show data for each region over time?

Tags: angular, echarts

I am using ngx-echarts verion: 14.0.0, with my angular application. I use echarts to display data on geoJson Maps.I am working on dynamically displaying count of some data by different departments of a country over time.

With the example and documentaion avaiable in Apache echarts https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-usa - I was able to create a map with the data as below.

I ask this question to understand what is the best way to dynamically change this data based on the year.

I tried using this example https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=mix-timeline-finance to try to use a similar approach, in the data formatting.

```
 dataFormatter(obj: any) {
    // prettier-ignore
    const pList = ['01', '15', '59'];
    let temp;
    for (let year = 2002; year <= 2011; year++) {
      let max = 0;
      let sum = 0;
      temp = obj[year];
      for (let i = 0, l = temp.length; i < l; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, temp[i]);
        sum += temp[i];
        obj[year][i] = {
          name: pList[i],
          value: temp[i]
        };
      }
      obj[year + 'max'] = Math.floor(max / 100) * 100;
      obj[year + 'sum'] = sum;
    }
    return obj;
  }
  
  mapFunction(chartData: CountsByDepartmentsModel[]): void {
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    echarts.registerMap('france', franceMap, 'france');
  
    this.dataMap.dataGDP = this.dataFormatter({
      //max : 60000,
      2011: [{name: '59', value: 5}, {name: '01', value: 2}, {name: '15', value: 3}],
      2010: [{name: '59', value: 10}, {name: '01', value: 4}, {name: '15', value: 6}],
      2009: [{name: '59', value: 15}, {name: '01', value: 6}, {name: '15', value: 9}],
      2008: [{name: '59', value: 20}, {name: '01', value: 8}, {name: '15', value: 12}],
      2007: [{name: '59', value: 25}, {name: '01', value: 10}, {name: '15', value: 15}],
      2006: [{name: '59', value: 30}, {name: '01', value: 12}, {name: '15', value: 18}],
      2005: [{name: '59', value: 35}, {name: '01', value: 14}, {name: '15', value: 21}],
      2004: [{name: '59', value: 40}, {name: '01', value: 16}, {name: '15', value: 24}],
      2003: [{name: '59', value: 45}, {name: '01', value: 18}, {name: '15', value: 27}],
      2002: [{name: '59', value: 50}, {name: '01', value: 20}, {name: '15', value: 30}]
    });
    
    // Get the count of the highest number of operators from all the departments to set as the MAX value in the graph
    const id = chartData.reduce((a,{counts}) => Number(counts) > a ? Number(counts) : a , -1);
    
    this.chartOptionsMap = {
      series: [
        {
          type: 'map',
          colorBy: 'series',
          map: 'france',
          roam: true,
          nameProperty:'code',
          label: {
            show: false
          },
          layoutCenter: ['50%','50%'],
          layoutSize: 550,
          selectedMode: false,
          [{ data: this.dataMap.dataGDP['2002'] }
          ],
          data: [
            {name: 59, value:25}]
        }
      ],
      tooltip: {
        show: true,
        trigger: 'item',
        showDelay: 0,
        transitionDuration: 0.2
      },
      visualMap: {
        left: 'right',
        min: 0,
        max: id,
        inRange: {
          color: [
            '#313695',
            '#4575b4',
            '#74add1',
            '#abd9e9',
            '#e0f3f8',
            '#ffffbf',
            '#fee090',
            '#fdae61',
            '#f46d43',
            '#d73027',
            '#a50026'
          ]
        },
        text: ['High', 'Low'],
        calculable: true
      },
      toolbox: {
        show: true,
        left: 'left',
        top: 'top',
        feature: {
          dataView: { readOnly: false },
          restore: {},
          saveAsImage: {}
        }
      },
    };
  }
```

But Im not too sure if I'm going in the right direction with this problem.

Comment: You can just modifiy your chart instance with [`myChart.setOption()`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption). This can be done based on a set timer, a button press or whatever you want. [This example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-race-country) might help. Heres another [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-bar-morph) with with a map.